# How to update android webview with internal storage data in browser

Tags: android, webview, local-storage

Am trying to load a webpage in Android using webview. In web browser, on inspect element, the data present in Application->Storage->LocalStorage, authenticates the user. How can i provide this data to webview. Right now it loads the url and gives authentication error.

Comment: provide your code. we have no idea what you are doing

Comment: @finki Am just trying to load url using webview's loadUrl function. When i inspect element in chrome, under application->storage->localstorage, there is some data. I need to provide the same in android webview as well. Don't know how to provide it.

Comment: @Jai what data do you want to provide?

Comment: @nimi0112 Its key-value pair i believe. Its the token.
 I tried to pass it as cookie, didn't work.

Comment: @Yvette Colomb: When you do any final action like delete on something, it's good to mention the reason as well. Just saying. I don't mind, i solved my issue anyways. :)