# How to read/write to local and session storage in android webview PWA?

Tags: android, webview, local-storage, progressive-web-apps

[A related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53514216/how-to-update-android-webview-with-internal-storage-data-in-browser) has been asked with no answer yet.

I have key/value pairs stored in local and session storage, how can I read/write/overwrite to this storage in my Android PWA's webview `MainActivity`?

Answer (score 1):

You could access the storage by using [evaluateJavasctript](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E))

```
myWebView.evaluateJavascript("window.localStorage.getItem('key')", value -> System.out.println(value)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but couple of days ago I needed to implement similar thing in my Android WebView project. All the information related to this topic was not useful and it was hard to find proper solution for this. I hope my answer will help someone who will need the same thing in future and will find this post as I did.

The main problem was that when I tried to add or read from session storage I was getting such error: `Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window'.`

I've tried a lot of things, but the solution is to evaluate javascript after page is loaded. For that I needed to create a `WebViewClient` class object and override `onPageFinished` method. And then add it to `WebView` during initializing. Also I needed enable `JavaScript` and `DomStorage` for my `WebView`. Complete `onCreate` method in `MainActivity` looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //some stuff...

    WebViewClient viewClient = new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            view.evaluateJavascript("sessionStorage.setItem(\"foo\", \"bar\");", null);
        }
    };

    WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.web);
    webView.setWebViewClient(viewClient);

    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    //some stuff..

    webView.loadUrl(<your_url>);
}
```